# Keyboard doesn't dismiss for TextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, keyboard, tableview, textfield

I have a strange problem with the iOS Keyboard.

In my app, I am using UITextFields inside some UITableViewCells. I want to dismiss the keyboard if the current textfield loses its focus.

This is what I've done so far:

- **Set up the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and add [textField resignFirstResponder] to textFieldDidEndEditing:**
- -> `textFieldDidEndEditing` gets called, but the keyboard stays.
- **Added all TextFields to an array, looped through all objects and call resignFirstResponder**
- -> No effect
- **Called [`self.tblView endEditing:YES`] inside textFieldDidEndEditing.**
- -> Keyboard didn't disappear.

But dismissing the keyboard by using the Done-Button works perfectly (using `textFieldShouldReturn`)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I've made a video of my problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zuz5rCv2GCo

Comment: How does the textfield knows that editing did end?

Comment: When I exit the textfield by getting into another one

Comment: Then you are in the next textfield -> keyboard visible.

Comment: Normally you are right! But I am using the TextFields inside a TableView. So If I tap on another TextField (in another row), the first one loses its focus and the second one isn't focused. (And the keyboard stays visible)

Comment: I made a Video of the problem .. [>Youtube<](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zuz5rCv2GCo) any ideas?

Comment: Can you call `[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: No, didSelectRowAtIndexPath won't be called if I tap on the textfield on the cell

Comment: ok, got my mistake .. I called [self.tblView reloadData] inside my textFieldDidEndEditing. Don't really know why this causes this error, but it works now! :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make this an answer and check it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try implementing following:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Also, try to see if didSelectRowAtIndexPath is getting called when you click other cell after editing. If it does, then call resignFirstResponder from there.